# sampe vector of points from truncated exponential distribution with specific average

Tags: python, random, scipy, statistics, distribution

I create a truncated exponential distribution:

```
from scipy.stats import truncexpon
truncexp = truncexpon(b = 8)
```

Now I want to sample 8 points from this distribution, such that their mean with be approximately 4.
What is the best way to do it without making a huge loop to randomly sample until the mean is close enough?

Comment: Some context would make it easier to help you.  Why are you doing this?  If you were to make "a huge loop to randomly sample until the mean is close enough", then your sample would no longer be a sample from the truncated exponential that you created!  So why create the truncated exponential in the first place?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I need to generate 8 elements, drawn from truncexp distribution, with mean of 4, min of 1 and max of 9. I am looking for the best way to do so

Comment: Do you want the mean of the 8 samples values to be exactly 4 (i.e. the *sample* mean is 4), or do you want the distribution to have an *expected* mean of 4, and draw 8 random samples from that distribution?  In the latter case, the actual mean of the 8 samples will not be exactly 4, just like the mean of 8 samples from a standard normal distribution would not be exactly 0.

Comment: OK, you did say "approximately 4" in the question.  But with only 8 samples, the mean of the sample from `truncexpon` with expected mean 4 could vary widely, and easily be less than 3 or greater than 5.

Answer (score 2):

The [`truncexpon`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncexpon.html) distribution has three parameters: a shape `b`, a location `loc` and a scale `scale`.  The support of the distribution is `[x1, x2]`, where `x1 = loc` and `x2 = shape*scale + loc`.  Solve the latter equation for `shape` to get `shape = (x2 - x1)/scale`. We'll choose the `scale` parameter so that the mean of the distribution is 4.  For that, we can use [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) applied to a function of the scale that is zero when `truncexpon.mean((x2 - x1)/scale, loc, scale)` is 4.

Here's a short script to demonstrate:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.stats import truncexpon


def func(scale, desired_mean, x1, x2):
    return truncexpon.mean((x2 - x1)/scale, loc=x1, scale=scale) - desired_mean


x1 = 1
x2 = 9

desired_mean = 4.0

# Numerically solve for the scale parameter of the truncexpon distribution
# with support [x1, x2] for which the expected mean is desired_mean.
scale_guess = 2.0
scale = fsolve(func, scale_guess, args=(desired_mean, x1, x2))[0]

# This is the shape parameter of the desired truncexpon distribution.
shape = (x2 - x1)/scale

print("Expected mean of the distribution is %6.3f" %
      (truncexpon.mean(shape, loc=x1, scale=scale),))
print("Expected standard deviation of the distribution is %6.3f" %
      (truncexpon.std(shape, loc=x1, scale=scale),))

# Generate a sample of size 8, and compute its mean.
sample = truncexpon.rvs(shape, loc=x1, scale=scale, size=8)
print("Mean of the sample of size %d is %6.3f" %
      (len(sample), sample.mean(),))

bigsample = truncexpon.rvs(shape, loc=x1, scale=scale, size=100000)
print("Mean of the sample of size %d is %6.3f" %
      (len(bigsample), bigsample.mean(),))
```

Typical output:

```
Expected mean of the distribution is  4.000
Expected standard deviation of the distribution is  2.178
Mean of the sample of size 8 is  4.694
Mean of the sample of size 100000 is  4.002
```

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful script, very useful! I noticed that your value for 'scale_guess' was the 'desired_mean /
2'. Using 'desired_mean / 2' as 'scale_guess', worked perfectly for a
different mean and different cut off scores in my case. To
enhance my understanding of your script, and increase its potential
generalisability, does this always have to be the case (i.e.,
'scale_guess' = 'desired_mean / 2')?

Comment: Referring back to the original question, could you summarize in plain
English what the script accomplished resp. highlight potential
shortcomings (you expressed your doubts in some of the above
comments)?

Comment: Just a minor point, my text editor notes that 'numpy as np' is not used. The script seems to work fine without it, at least from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

The mean is a characteristic of your distribution. If you continue to sample values, the empirical mean will simply become closer and closer to the analytical mean.

Scipy can tell you the mean of your truncated exponential:

```
b = 8
truncexp = truncexpon(b)
truncexp.mean() # 0.99731539839326999
```

You can use the distribution to sample and calculate the empirical mean:

```
num_samples = 100000
np.mean(truncexp.rvs(num_samples)) # 0.99465816346645264
```

An analytical formula to calculate the mean is this (second line):

```
b = np.linspace(0.1, 20, 100)
m = 1/ ((1 - np.exp(-b)) / ((1 - (b + 1)*np.exp(-b))))
```

If you plot this, you can see how the mean behaves for different values of b.

[image]

For b -> inf, the mean will go towards 1. You'll not find a b with mean 4.

If you want to sample from a truncated exponential, with a mean of 4, you can simply scale the samples. This will not give you samples from the original distribution, but then again, samples from the original distribution will never give you that mean of 4.

```
truncexp.rvs(num_samples) * 4 / truncexp.mean()
```

Comment: what is the rvs() function? I couldn't find any doc of it

Comment: it's on the docs site for truncexpon, scroll down a bit: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncexpon.html#scipy.stats.truncexpon

Comment: thanks but I don't sure I understand - why b=8 if it is not num of samples?

Comment: did you read the docs? The probability density function contains a parameter b, and that is what you specify in the constructor